# Android CROP error

Tags: android, crop

Sometime I have an error, when I'm trying to make a crop from camera only in samsung galaxy s2. How can I solve it?

```
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cooliris.media/com.cooliris.media.CropImage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at com.cooliris.media.CropImage.loadBitmap(CropImage.java:447)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at com.cooliris.media.CropImage.onCreate(CropImage.java:430)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
07-03 17:25:13.643: E/AndroidRuntime(12485):    ... 11 more
07-03 17:25:13.653: E/android.os.Debug(1973): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -n -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: post your code on CropImage.java@ line number 430.

Comment: its not my code, CropImage.java - its a Gallery3D by samsung s2, I can show it, but...    430. midPoint.y *= mScale;

Comment: com.cooliris.media.CropImage if your are using this activity in your project just add this in your manifest.xml.

Comment: Perhaps you have the same problem like me...
I solved my issue - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893520/take-and-crop-image-with-cooliris